# How do I patch the Mobile Device Browser File

Tags: asp.net, mobile-devices

[Nexus One](http://www.google.com/phone/) is not currently supported by the [Mobile Device Browser File](http://mdbf.codeplex.com), which leads to the Nexus One being identified as a non mobile device.

I know the user agent, and the capabilities are pretty similar to other Android terminals. With this information, how do I patch the MDBF to have the N1 be recognized as a mobile device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding [Mobile Device Browser File](http://mdbf.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=219552):

Quote: "Due to the organizational restructuring of the team that developed and supported the Mobile Device Browser file, we will no longer have the resources to support and update this CodePlex project. The team will be providing two more releases – one on the 27th July 2010 and the final release on the 24th August 2010."

Answer (score 0):

not sure if it is helpful to you but you can check for Nexus in the user agent field returned by the browser.

Comment: I already have the user agent string:

Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.1; en-gb; Nexus One Build/ERD79) AppleWebKit/530.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/530.17

The problem is that the MDBF doesn't include it (since it is new), so I'm wondering what the recommended procedure is for manually patching the MDBF?